# async/await in Firebase Storage (wait to get URL after uploading a file)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm useing Firestore in my Vue project and I'm working on a feature that allows users to upload images, however I'm facing the following issue:

I have a 'newMarker' placeholder object that the user fills in with information and once the user confirms the input, the object is saved to the database. When the user confirms the input I want to:

1. Save the image in Firebase Storage
2. Get the generated URL for that file
3. Add the URL to the newMarker object
4. and then push the newMarker object with the included imgURL to the database

However I can't figure out how to make the code wait for the callback function that runs as soon as the upload status is completed (in the uploadIMG function, 'uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED', last callback function) and returns a promise with the url. No matter what I do, this callback function is executed last.

When the user confirms the input, saveNewMarker() is executed and the following code will run:

My code:

```
    async saveNewMarker() {
        await this.uploadImg();
        console.log('Image upload finished! Pushing new marker to db')

        await db.collection(this.user.email).add({
            position: this.newMarker.position,
            type: this.newMarker.type,
            location: this.newMarker.location,
            imgURL: this.newMarker.imgURL
        })
        .then((marker) => {
            console.log('marker added to database')
            this.newMarker.id = marker.id
        })
    },
    async uploadImg(){
        console.log('Uploading image ...')
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        const uploadTask = storageRef.child('user-uploads/images/' + this.file.name).put(this.name)

        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, 
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            }, 
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }, 
            async () => {
                const imgURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
                console.log('uploaded image: ' + imgURL)
                this.newMarker.imgURL = imgURL
            }
        );
    },
```

Output:

```
Uploading image ...
Upload is NaN% done
Image upload finished! Pushing new marker to db
marker added to database
uploaded image: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....
```

Expected output:

```
Uploading image ...
Upload is NaN% done
uploaded image: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....
Image upload finished! Pushing new marker to db
marker added to database
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how async/awaits are intended to be used, I would recommend using Promises instead, like this:

```
function saveNewMarker() {
    // Call uploadImg as a Promise and wait for the result
    this.uploadImg()
        .then((imgURL) => {
            console.log('Image upload finished! Pushing new marker to db');

            db.collection(this.user.email).add({
                position: this.newMarker.position,
                type: this.newMarker.type,
                location: this.newMarker.location,
                imgURL: this.newMarker.imgURL
            })
                .then((marker) => {
                    console.log('marker added to database');
                    this.newMarker.id = marker.id;
                })
        }).catch((error) => {
        //Do something
        });
};

function uploadImg() {
    // Return a promise that will either resolve or emit an error
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Uploading image ...');
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        const uploadTask = storageRef.child('user-uploads/images/' + this.file.name).put(this.name);

        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                // An error occurred so inform the caller
                reject(error);
            },
            async () => {
                const imgURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                console.log('uploaded image: ' + imgURL);
                this.newMarker.imgURL = imgURL;

                // We 'awaited' the imgURL, now resolve this Promise
                resolve(imgURL);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

And remember your semicolons to avoid unintended behavior or errors.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wrap code within `uploadImg` in promise and resolve it once image upload is done. Refactoring `uploadImg` to something like below should work:

```
async uploadImg() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Uploading image ...");
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child("user-uploads/images/" + this.file.name).put(this.name);

    uploadTask.on(
      firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      },
      async () => {
        const imgURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log("uploaded image: " + imgURL);
        this.newMarker.imgURL = imgURL;
        resolve();
      }
    );
  });
},
```