# Wait for Firebase file upload downloadURL in file to store it in object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm uploading images with the original Google-code from:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

```
    uploadImage(image){       
    var metadata = {
              contentType: 'image/jpeg'
            };
            const file = base64ToFile(image)
            // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
            var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref(this.currentUser.uid).child(imgName + '.jpg').put(file, metadata);
        
            // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
            uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
              (snapshot) => {
                // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
                var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                switch (snapshot.state) {
                  case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                  case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
                }
              },
              (error) => {
                // A full list of error codes is available at
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
                switch (error.code) {
                  case 'storage/unauthorized':
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break;
                  case 'storage/canceled':
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break;
        
                  // ...
        
                  case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                    break;
                }
              },
              () => {
                // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
                  console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
return downloadURL
                });
              }
            );
    }
```

The upload is done in my service and now I want to wait in my file till the donwloadURL is ready and then save it to my object. I need the donwloadURL returned direct to my file, because I want to do some other things with my object after uploading and save the object at last. Is there an opportunity to wait for or return the downloadURL? Like

```
this.dataService.uploadImage(file).then(data => { object.url = data })
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see a `then()`, you can use [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to make the code a bit simpler to read. So you can do this if you want:

```
async () => {
  const downloadURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
}
```

But you'll note that I also had to mark the function itself as `async` now. So any use of the download URL must happen within this asynchronous function itself.

---

The `task` itself is also a promise (so, it has a `then`), which means that you can also use `await` there. So if we remove all the progress reporting and error handling, the code can also be written as:

```
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};
const file = base64ToFile(image)
const ref = firebase.storage().ref(this.currentUser.uid).child(imgName + '.jpg');
await ref.put(file, metadata);

const downloadURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
```

Here too, since we're using `await`, the function that you put this code in will have to be marked as `async`, and any use of the `downloadURL` needs to be inside the function, or you can use `await` in the calling code again.

Comment: Thanks, I think this side is now clear so far. My problem ist still, that I've a upload function in my normal file: this.dataService.uploadImage(file).then(data => {
        object.url = data
      }) and want to get back the downloadURL here (returned from the dataService)

Comment: I edited the question and hope that it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Found the searched way here: [async/await in Firebase Storage (wait to get URL after uploading a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098139/async-await-in-firebase-storage-wait-to-get-url-after-uploading-a-file)

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
...code before...
 resolve(downloadURL); //instead of return downloadURL
});
```

made it for me